# How to round to two decimal places PHP

Tags: php, drupal, decimal, drupal-webform

I would like to round a number to two decimal places in PHP.

PHP code:

```
$bmi = ($form_state[values][submitted][1] * 703) / 
    ($form_state[values][submitted][10] * $form_state[values][submitted][10]);
$form_values['submitted'][11] = $bmi;
$form_values['submitted_tree'][11] = $bmi;
```

What is the best way to round the variable `$bmi`?

Comment: yep simply typing "round" into php.net search box gives you instant results on such topics

Comment: Thanks Greg, I did try this beforehand though and it didn't work....

Comment: if you pass in a number to the function `round` then it would work. What does it return for you? Maybe your problem does not lie with the usage of round.

Comment: Abs, Have edited the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit3:

Well if I understand your code right it should go like this:

```
<?php
    //Calculate $bmi
    $bmi = ($form_state[values][submitted][1] * 703) / 
       ($form_state[values][submitted][10] * $form_state[values][submitted][10]);

    //Fill unrounded $bmi var into array for whatever reason
    $form_values['submitted'][11] = $bmi;

    //Fill unrounded $bmi var into array for whatever reason
    $form_values['submitted_tree'][11] = $bmi;

    //$bmi contains for example 24.332423
    $bmi = round($bmi,2);

    //Should output 24.33
    echo $bmi;
?>
```

If anything goes wrong I can only assume that the calculated $bmi var gets messed up somewhere.

Is it supposed that you fill the unrounded value into $form_values['submitted'][11]? if not try the following:

```
 $bmi = ($form_state[values][submitted][1] * 703) / ($form_state[values][submitted][10] *  
 $bmi = round($bmi,2); 
 $form_values['submitted'][11] = $bmi;
 $form_values['submitted_tree'][11] = $bmi;
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of variable (value of the variable) is stored in $bmi before you try to round the value?

Comment: @jeremy Phrases like "it didn't work" really don't help anybody. To get the most of out this site (and so many other things in life) please provide the inputs and outputs (both actual and expected). I guarantee that if you make it as simple as possible to understand your issue that you'll have your answer in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Inetersting Alex thankyopu for taking the time to try this out, I tried both these approaches and neither seemed to work - could it be becuase the $bmi is not recognised as a number value?

Comment: "neither seemed to work" please tell us what exactly didn't work. Does it round wrong? Doesn't it round at all? We need some information to be able to help you. Please post some test values you used.

Comment: The output is exactly the same (28.69387755102), so no rounding at all.

Comment: It seems you are doing the rounding at the wrong location in your code if nothing happens at all. Could you please post the snippet where you fill the $bmi war and round it

Comment: Hi Alex, I edited my question with examples of your edits used by me.

Comment: Edited again, please try it out and tell me your result

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it makes sense that it would work.  I will attack the Drupal forums and see if anyone else can help me - may be an issue wit Drupal Webform module.  thanks again.

Comment: Indeed that last option works!  Needed to round it before it filling it inot fields 11.  Thanks so much for your perseverance Alex1

Answer (score 10):

```
round ($your_variable, 2)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 3):

PHP `round` will take a number and round it to 2 units precision:

```
$foo = 105.5555;
echo round($foo, 2);                    //prints 105.56
```

Or a string and round it to 2 units precision:

```
$bmi = "52.44444";
echo round($bmi, 2);                    //prints 52.44
```

Round to two units precision, and force a minimum precision this way:

```
$foo = 105.5555;
echo number_format(round($foo, 2), 4, '.', '');  //prints 105.5600
```

Comment: Thanks Abs, having some slight issues with it, but im sure Ill come to the right code.